# javascript conflict with jquery fadein of button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a conflict with my javascript which is causing elements not to fadein. I have a button set to fadein after 10 seconds which works fine when I remove my javascript that I'm using for something else.

Can anyone help me figure out what the conflict might be?

You can see the test page I'm working on here: https://training.handcraftedbusinessfilms.com/test-fade-in/

I've currently removed the javascript that is causing the conflict but you can see it below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Custom code by James
    jQuery( document ).ready( function ( jQuery ) { 
        // binds to the plugin's function 
        jQuery( "input[name='gform_payment_method']" ).on( 'click', gfpStripeToggleCreditCard() );
        // triggers the change to default option 
        jQuery( "input[id^=gform_payment_method_card_]" ).click();
        console.log("Hello James");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro, your script is correct, but I see that you have 2 calls of "document.ready" in different parts of the html, so just need use once. I have merged and tested the script in the "head" tag and it works:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div.button").fadeIn(2000);

        //By James
        //binds to the plugin's function 
        jQuery( "input[name='gform_payment_method']" ).on( 'click', gfpStripeToggleCreditCard );
        //triggers the change to default option 
        jQuery( "input[id^=gform_payment_method_card_]" ).click();
        console.log("Hello James");

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm still having the same issue.

I've made a short video showing the issue as well here: http://www.screencast.com/t/pTTCLwpCVy

Answer (score 0):

The jquery was being called before it was defined in the header b/c the scripts were injected into the header via the theme and we couldn't control exactly the order of the scripts.

The solution was to create a [site specific plugin](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/what-why-and-how-tos-of-creating-a-site-specific-wordpress-plugin/) that set a function to hold off on calling any jquery before the jquery was defined.